# How to show all excel sheet?

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have an excel 2007 file with many sheets and I need to hide or show all of them (except one).

It is easy to hide all the sheet, but how to show all the 200 sheets togheter?

I know I can write a macro to show the sheets but to ride this way I have to extract all the sheets name to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd have to extract all the sheet names.

**Hiding sheets**

AFAIK there are two ways to do it.

Select all the sheets that you want to hide, and then right-click and select "hide".
Or, On the *Home tab*, in the *Cells* group, click *Format*,
and under *Visibility*, click *Hide & Unhide*, and then click *Hide Sheet*.

[image]

The other way of doing it is by looping the sheets with a simple macro, hiding all sheets apart from the currently selected one:

```
Sub hideSheets()
Dim wS As Worksheet, Current As String
Current = ActiveSheet.Name
For Each wS In Worksheets
    If Not wS.Name = Current Then
        wS.Visible = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Showing sheets**

To show all the sheets again, the code is even simpler.

```
Sub showSheets()
Dim wS As Worksheet
For Each wS In Worksheets
        wS.Visible = True
Next
End Sub
```

*Extra*

If you want to target a specific sheet, that isn't the currently active one (to hide all but, or show all but), simply change the `Current = ActiveSheet.Name` to `Current = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")` and you get to name the sheet in an inputbox instead.

Comment: I edit the question because the problem is on showing all the sheets

Comment: @Ale Added simple macro to show all the sheets.