# All the excel sheets disappeared except the first one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I got stuck into a strange problem I never came across with **MS Excel** till date... I'm using latest version of MS office 365 ProPlus. The last time I updated my office was nearly 2 weeks back. I have configured for manual update so no auto-update. Let me define the problem!

**Problem**: ***All the sheets*** (nearly 5-6 in a file) except the first one, ***disappeared/deleted*** all of a sudden! Now, ***every excel file*** that I open on my system, ends up with the same thing.

I checked for it in different folders, recycle bin but no luck. The file exists but only with the first sheet. Tried to run file recovery software but none of the excel files is been deleted in last 1 month, so there is nothing to find. Also I have no macros running on my excel.

**What I have tried**:

1. [How to show all excel sheet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1181288/how-to-show-all-excel-sheet)
2. http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/recover-missing-sheet-tabs-microsoft-excel
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4PTnryZxh8

I tried to google but seems there is no such problem. Also, I **didn't change** any of the **settings** recently! This happened all of a sudden today noon. Is this some kind of bug? or something else?

I would be really great-full if someone can please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they being saved as a `.csv` or `.txt` file?

Comment: nop! all of them are saved in `.xlsx` format.

Comment: If you make a new file, add some tabs, save, close, and re-open, is it back down to just one tab?

Comment: @Engineer Toast: yes! That's what happens. All the other sheets disappear.

Comment: I am not too sure how 365 Pro plus works, but assuming it's on local PC like desktop/laptop, first create a test file. Add 4 -5 sheets in it. Populate the sheets with some considerable random data. Save but do not close. Now go to File Properties and check the file size. Close and reopen and again check the file size, is it same or less after losing all but first sheet? Also what if you try to open the sheet on some other system? May be send it to someone and ask them to open on their version of Excel?

Comment: Another thing I would recommend at this point is consider taking backups of all your Excel files on some external drive. If re-installation and reactivation is possible, try uninstalling Office and do a fresh install and activation and do not update. Then check again.

Comment: @patkim I have tested as you said. the file sizes differ before & after losing data. Te sheets are actually getting deleted I believe. Yes I tried to repair and reinstall Office but that dint work.

Comment: Thoroughly scan your system for any possible virus/malware etc.

Comment: Try starting Excel in safe mode, and see if the behavior persists.  Try changing the extension on a file with the problem to `.zip`. Then examine it to see if there is any sign of the missing worksheets.